# Design questions for an OOP library in Lua

Tags: oop, lua

I implemented a small OOP library in Lua, and two things are not quite right yet. I need your advice!

### How to call super()?

I need to make a choice. The three arguments I need to resolve a call to super() are:

- The class from where the call is being made (CallerClass)
- The instance to be passed (self)
- The name of the method (method)

I hesitate between these three forms:

```
--# Current way:
self:super(CallerClass):method()

--# Variant, which I now find cleaner:
CallerClass:super(self):method()

--# Python style, which is nice too:
super(CallerClass, self):method()
```

Which one looks nicer and or easier to remember to you?

### Do I need a Class symbol?

In the current version, the only concept is a table named `Object`, which you can subclass. I have another version where I introduced a Class symbol.

Its use is to tell instances from classes. I.e. :

```
assert(Object:isKindOf(Class))
local object = Object:new()
assert(not object:isKindOf(Class))
```

I find it very handy to document and enforce that a method must be called from a class, by starting the method with:

```
assert(self:isKindOf(Class))
```

Is it usefull in Lua? What do you think? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--# Python style, which is nice too:
super(CallerClass, self):method()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say have a class object - more info/metadata is better

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chris, done.

For those interested, the code is published on the Lua Users Wiki, see [ObjectLua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectLua).